# VBA - find empty cells, set equal to "EMPTY"

Tags: vba, excel, is-empty

Code finds values from sheets and copies them over to one sheet. If a column is completely empty, it prints "NO ITEMS".

I need to make it so, once it is done copying the items over, it **finds any blank cells in column "B"** *(StartSht, "B")* and from the range of the last occupied cell of "C" up, **fills it with the string "EMPTY"**

Any ideas how I would go about doing that?

It does (1) and I need it to do (2)

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

```
Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
If dict.count > 0 Then                  
    'add the values to the master list, column 2
    Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
Else
    'if no items are under the HOLDER header
    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = " NO ITEMS "
End If
```

Comment: What specifically have you tried to find blank cells?  Is there any reason all of the normal ways of finding blank cells are inappropriate, or are you just not aware of those ways?  This would include the common: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` and looping through and checking `Range.Value <> ""`.  I assume you know how to set the value once you find the blanks?

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with it _(learned that Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) existed about 20 minutes ago)_ and I do not know how to set a range that I mentioned in the question. Every time I try, I get an error that I've set a range that isn't possible @Byron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "B"), 2), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "EMPTY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Blank cells are easy to find with the `SpecialCells` function.  It is the same as using GoTo (or hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>) and choosing `Blanks`.

```
StartSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "EMPTY"
```

You can do the same for column C after building the appropriate range.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Yes that is great except for one thing. I am looping through a file so I need it to just fill the empty cells from the last filled row in C up to the top of B. Is there any way to do that? @Byron

Comment: I guess your question says `find any blank cells in column B` so I keyed in on that.  What does `to the top of B` mean?  What cell address are you trying to get to?  `B1`?  Regardless, there should be plenty of other references for how to build the ranges.

Comment: Sorry yes I see how I worded that poorly. I added pictures of what it does vs what I want it to do. It opens multiple files so I need it to only find the empty cells in that range. There are other references but none I have found worked for this, at least I am not implementing them correctly. I have tried dozens of different methods and nothing has given me a succesful result @Byron . Each file goes through a loop so I simply want it to fill the empty cells with EMPTY after each looop so that the cells are occupied and will not be printed over by the next loop